# MySql Job or decent never ending loop

Tags: mysql

I'm searching for a kind of MySql job, let me explain my problem.

Basically i have a table (representing my queueing list), this table contain a field "action" and a field "end date". "end date" is represent the time when i have to launch the action.

What i need is a job, or infinite loop, who's constantly checking the "end date" field, and when this field, this date, is corresponding to the actual date, then execute an action (SQL Query).

Hope you guys can give me some tips ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think [`MySQL EVENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) can be used for such purpose.

Example:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE EVENT Every_5_minutes_e
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 5 MINUTE
    STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY       --- starting tomorrow
    ENDS '2099-12-31 23:59:59'                      --- ending in 2099
  COMMENT 'Check queuing list and perform actions'
  DO
    BEGIN
      DECLARE actionstatus_doingnow VARCHAR(255);
      SET actionstatus_doingnow = CONCAT('Doing now ', NOW()) ;

      UPDATE QueueingList                       --- mark actions that will be done
      SET ActionStatus = actionstatus_doingnow  --- by this event
      WHERE EndDatetime <= NOW()
        AND ActionStatus = 'To Be Done'  ;

      ...                                       --- code for doing the actions 

      UPDATE QueueingList                         --- mark actions as finished
      SET ActionStatus = 'Done'
      WHERE ActionStatus = actionstatus_doingnow ;
    END $$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: The problem is that my table will be check only every 5 minutes, so it's not "real time"...

Comment: That is just an example. You can put `EVERY 1 SECOND` if you like.

Comment: How many actions do you plan to have? One every minute? One every day? Many per second?  Sometimes this and sometimes that?

Comment: Constantly, it's for a multiplayer game, so as mush as they are players, as mush as i have actions...

Comment: A simple `IF EXISTS ...` just after the `BEGIN` of the event code may allow you to run this every few seconds (or even more frequently). The actual code will be exectued only when you have actions to do in the `QueueingList` table.

Comment: Constantly is not an answer really. How many actions per second do you expect to have?